# Should I use -ing in the following case?

Tags: grammar, verbs

> Nothing beats the feeling of flipping through real paper;
>   trace its contours, take in its musty scent.

I'm a bit confused. Should I write:

> ...**tracing** its contours, **taking** in the musty scent.

Instead?

Comment: Absolutely! Otherwise it sounds like hell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your original sentence, the grammar is technically correct, but "trace" and "take" are *imperative commands*. Consider the same words, formatted differently:

> Nothing beats the feeling of flipping through real paper. Trace its contours! Take in its musty scent!

You are directly commanding the reader (or someone) to trace and to take. The "*Nothing beats ... real paper*" is one complete independent clause and the "*trace its ... musty scent" is another. They are joined by a semicolon.

---

The following is also correct (but not very poetic):

> Nothing beats the feeling of flipping through real paper, tracing its contours, and taking in its musty scent.

Here, the preposition *of* has three objects (joined by *and*): *flipping*, *tracing*, and *taking*. These are all [gerunds, ending with *-ing*](http://www.englishpage.com/gerunds/part_1.htm), and they meaning "*the act of flipping*", etc.

If you want to be more poetic (and less formal), you can remove *and*:

> Nothing beats the feeling of flipping through real paper, tracing its contours, taking in its musty scent.

For any list, we must consistently use a comma (***,***) instead of a semicolon (***;***). When separating items from a list, you should separate them all by commas. Very rarely you can use semicolons, when the list follows a colon (***:***) and the items of the list have commas inside of them, like:

> I met three people today: Jane, the sailor; Daniel, the cook; and Eli, the soldier.

Comment: The missing "and" burns my eyes, honestly.  It doesn't sound poetic to me; it just sounds wrong.  Otherwise, excellent answer.  :)

Comment: (Native AmE) I find the version without **and** more poetic. It encourages the reader to imagine, by suggesting that there is more sensory experience than explicitly stated. The version with **and** suggests that the list is complete and exhaustive: nothing beats the feeling of _exactly those three things._ The suggestion of exhaustiveness made by **and** is so implausible, including it almost seems like an error.